# Ember.js and jQuery transitions, based on property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js, handlebars.js

Sorry if this question is too basic, I'm very new to Ember.js... I've read about didInsertElement/willDestroy being a good point to use jQuery transitions in an Ember template, but am wondering about situations where content is displayed based on a property being set, like this:

```
<div>First content area</div>

{{#if isSomeProperty }}
    <div>Second content area</div>
{{/if}}

<div>Third content area</div>
```

Is there a way for me to add a jQuery slideDown();, for example, when isSomeProperty is set to true? Or do I really just need to put the code for the second content area in a component so I can use didInsertElement/willDestroy?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read about `Observers` yet? http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/.

You'll probably want to observe `isSomeProperty` in the corresponding ember view, then check it's value and execute the animation when `isSomeProperty` is true. Let me know if you need any more help ;)

Comment: Then would I just animate the unhiding of the inner div, rather than try to attach it to the show/hide of the ember-view div that gets generated?

Comment: You could also check the property in `didInsertElement` and then start the animation. This is just a way to start the animation in the case that isSomeProperty is set to true _after_ the parent element has been inserted.

Comment: Also in case you didn't know, you can use `this.$().find('.child-element')` to target a child element.